# React Horizontal Scrolling cards with Arrows on top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

Currently I'm using [React-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/responsive) for my horizontal card scrollview, but the output is not what I exactly want. What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Where the 1 card in the front and 1 card in the back are shown half and the arrows overlap the front and back card.
But currently my arrows show up in the start and end of the cards and all the cards are equally fit in one page.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-chaplygin-jydsu?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div className={className} style={{ background: "#fff" }} onClick={onClick}>
      <img
        style={{ width: "20px" }}
        src="https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/302-3023323_arrow-pointing-to-right-comments-right-arrow-png.png"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function SamplePrevArrow(props) {
  const { className, style, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <div className={className} style={{ background: "#fff" }} onClick={onClick}>
      <img
        style={{ width: "20px" }}
        src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/arrow-pointing-to-the-left-115501167743epfu1fapc.png"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default class Responsive extends Component {
  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      initialSlide: 0,
      nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
      prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            initialSlide: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Responsive </h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize the `slack css` and change the default `slack` styles. Add bellow styles to `css` which have imported to the component:

```
.slick-prev {
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.slick-prev:before {
  content: "";
}
.slick-next {
  right: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.slick-next:before {
  content: "";
}
```

Also for showing the cards not in fit mode, you need to add the `centerMode` setting to `slack settings`:

```
  className: "center",
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "60px",
```

Plus, add these styles:

```
.center .slick-center h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

h3 {
  background: #5f9ea0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Edit epic-darwin-r71ww]

Comment: Is there anyway to show the 1st and last card to be seen partially like in my reference image above?

Comment: @JJM50 Updated the answer. Please check it again.